# SwiftUI TextField Decimal Numbers Validation

Tags: swiftui

I am implementing an app that allows user's to decimal numbers in a SwiftUI TextField. I achieved that using the following code.

```
 @State private var total: Double = 0.0

 TextField("Total", value: $total, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

The problem is that how do I validate that the TextField contains a number greater than zero and also that the user has input something and not left blank.

Here is my code:

```
var isValid: Bool {
     total > 0
}
```

But the user can still leave the field blank and it will reset to the last double value they used.

Comment: doesn't it work if you reset the total to 0 after each input and check for values > 0 – then you would always get valid inputs ...?

Comment: The isValid property is evaluated each time someone types something and it is passed to the Button disable modifier to make the button disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around with a classic text input:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var input = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Total", text: $input)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            Button("Confirm") {
                // do something with Double(input)
                print(Double(input))
                self.input = ""
            }
            .disabled( Double(input) ?? 0 <= 0 )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```